# Bootstrap carousel in rails 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to create a bootstrap carousel for the homepage of a blog that scrolls through the last three articles from the database. I got it working for a carousel that advances automatically but I wanted to have the next and previous buttons but when I try in that one it does not work.  I can get the first which is the last article in the table to display but it will not advance.

I couldn't figure out out a better way to get the last three articles so here is ow I did it.  I am definitely open to suggestions to make this better.  My home action for the pages_controller is:

```
def home 
    @articles = Article.last(3).reverse
    @art1 = @articles.pop
    @art2 = @articles.pop
    @art3 = @articles.pop
  end
```

Now the carousel:

```
<div id="carouselExampleCaptions" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-bs-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-bs-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-bs-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-bs-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-bs-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-bs-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <%= image_tag(@art3.image.url, width: '100%') %>
      <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
        <h5><%= @art3.title %></h5>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <%= image_tag(@art2.image.url, width: '100%') %>
      <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
        <h5><%= @art2.title %></h5>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <%= image_tag(@art1.image.url, width: '100%') %>
      <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
        <h5><%= @art1.title %></h5>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleCaptions" role="button" data-bs-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleCaptions" role="button" data-bs-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

This works in the works in a version of the carousel that does not have buttons but advances automatically.

Comment: Do you see any Javascript error in the browser's console when you try that?

Comment: No, I don't see anything in the console or the server log when I lick on the links.